# Save graph from URI

Tags: c#, rdf, dotnetrdf, linkedmdb

My question is how to save all the triples in my graph variable from URI. When I execute my code:

```
IGraph g = new Graph();
g.LoadFromUri(new Uri("http://data.linkedmdb.org/page/film/14931"));
```

I get only 2 triples in that graph, my question is how can I get others like actors, director, editor,...?

Those 2 triples are:

```
{http://data.linkedmdb.org/page/film/14931 , http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/vocab#stylesheet , http://data.linkedmdb.org/snorql/style.css}
{http://data.linkedmdb.org/page/film/14931 , http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/vocab#alternate , http://data.linkedmdb.org/data/film/14931}
```

Comment: It sounds like you're not actually getting much in the way of RDF content.  Perhaps content-type negotiation isn't being performed?  But even if it it, just because a URI identifies a resource doesn't mean that requesting that URI as a URL will retrieve content about it.  Do you have a reason to suppose that you're *supposed* to be able to request that URI?

Comment: I have task to get all the triples from that resource without using SPARQL queries, can I do that?

Comment: "all the triples from that resource"  What does that mean?  A resource isn't a container.  A resource is a resource.  It doesn't have any triples.  A graph can contain triples that use a resource as a subject, property, or value, but that's different from the resource itself.  After all, part of the point of using URIs as identifiers is that it makes it *easier* for other people to write triples about the same resource.  There's no possible way to know all the triples about a resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LinkedMDB homepage includes:

> #### [Start Exploring](http://data.linkedmdb.org/)
>
> - Use your web browser to explore the HTML view provided by the D2R
>     server at
>     http://data.linkedmdb.org/page/film/2014
> - Use the following
>     semantic web browsers to explore the resource URI
>     http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/film/2014

It sounds like you should request http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/film/14931 instead.  (Note that retrieving that in a *web browser*, you'll get redirected to the first.  Be sure to try it in your code, not just in a web browser.)

Comment: After I put that into my code I get all the triples I need